# Comparing string values within a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to compare two columns with strings to each other, and getting the matches?

I have two columns containing Names, once with the Full Name the other with (mostly) just the Surname.

I just tried it with soundex, but it will just return if the values are almost similar in both columns.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE soundex(FullName) = soundex(Surname)
```

```
1   John Doe       Doe 
2   Peter Parker   Parker
3   Brian Griffin  Brian Griffin
```

with soundex it will only match the 3rd line.

Comment: `SOUNDEX()` is an outdated function that doesn't really have good use in this century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use instring function,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE instr(Surname, FullName) > 0;


SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE instr(upper(Surname), upper(FullName)) > 0;

SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE upper(FullName) > upper(Surname);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to work for me too :)
(i got more results by adding UPPER for case sensitivity)

Comment: If you feel its correct, please mark as correct, so that others will be helpful. Have provided you other ways of achieving it

Comment: The last query doesn't make much sense. `'JOHN SMITH' > 'ABE LINCOLN'`, because `'J' > 'A'`, so it's a match??? As to the other queries: `INSTR('JOHN', 'MARC JOHNSSON'`) = 6`, so that's a match, too?

Comment: Its not a Match, < and > operator serves as a comparison. If you wanted to check if a string is available in another column you can use these operators. Just try it, you can understand

Comment: Okay, I tried it. I suppose that you confused the positions in `INSTR`, so I also added your expressions with switched parameters. Here is a demo with six instead of your three expressions; none of them works reliably: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25b56025fba062eed7d843a4a621430e

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to use `instr`, which shows whether `surname` exists in `fullname`:

```
SQL> with test (id, fullname, surname) as
  2    (select 1, 'John Doe'     , 'Doe'           from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Peter Parker' , 'Parker'        from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Brian Griffin', 'Brian Griffin' from dual
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from test
  8  where instr(fullname, surname) > 0;

        ID FULLNAME      SURNAME
---------- ------------- -------------
         1 John Doe      Doe
         2 Peter Parker  Parker
         3 Brian Griffin Brian Griffin
```

---

Another option is to use one of `UTL_MATCH` functions, e.g. Jaro-Winkler similarity which shows how well those strings *match*:

```
SQL> with test (id, fullname, surname) as
  2    (select 1, 'John Doe'     , 'Doe'           from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Peter Parker' , 'Parker'        from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Brian Griffin', 'Brian Griffin' from dual
  5    )
  6  select id, fullname, surname,
  7    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(fullname, surname) jws
  8  from test
  9  order by id;

        ID FULLNAME      SURNAME              JWS
---------- ------------- ------------- ----------
         1 John Doe      Doe                   48
         2 Peter Parker  Parker                62
         3 Brian Griffin Brian Griffin        100

SQL>
```

Feel free to explore other function that package offers.

---

Also, note that I didn't pay attention to possible letter case differences (e.g. "DOE" vs. "Doe"). If you need that as well, compare e.g. `upper(surname)` to `upper(fullname)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to work for me perferctly :) (as you mentionend UPPER i really got more results by adding it to my select)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is nothing out of the box when matching becomes complicated. For the cases shown, however, the following expression would suffice:

```
where fullname like '%' || surname
```

### Update

The main problem may be false positives:

- The last name 'Park' appears in 'Peter Parker'. Above query solves this by looking at the full name's end.

Another problem may be upper / lower case as mentioned in the other answers (not shown in your sample data).

- You want the last name 'PARKER' match 'Peter Parker'.

But when looking at the strings case insensitively, another problem arises:

- The last name 'Strong' will suddenly match 'Louis Armstrong'.

A solution for this is to add a blank to make the difference:

```
where ' ' || upper(fullname) like '% ' || upper(surname)
```

- `' LOUIS ARMSTRONG' like '% STRONG'` -> false
- `' LOUIS ARMSTRONG' like '% ARMSTRONG'` -> true
- `' LOUIS ARMSTRONG' like '% LOUIS ARMSTRONG'` -> true

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0ac5c80061b4aeac1153a8c5976e6e54

Comment: thanks, this is also a very smart way to get matches

Comment: Thanks :-) As the accepted answer is wrong, but case sensitivity mentioned in the other two answers has its point, I've updated my answer to allow for case mismatches, too.